# umbraco richtext editor deleted

Tags: umbraco, rich-text-editor

I had a problem with **umbraco richtext editor**, it was not letting me insert images, so I followed a forum and **deleted the richtext editor datatype** in the developer section, then i recreated the richtext editor datatype with the same settings.

**My problem is**: all the properties in the node which were of type RichText editor have disappeared from the content pages. **i cant see the text and the editor. But i can still see the content on the website!**

so i cannot edit them from the content section but i can see them on the website!

Kindly, help!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to add the bodyText property (or whatever you were using) to the document type(s) again. It's possible that the data was also removed, so beware republishing a node until you have the text back in there.

The reason you can still see the content on the site is because when a node is published, it's properties are cached. When the site has to access a property for the front end, it pulls it from the cache rather than getting it directly from the database. This allows the site to perform faster.

So add the rich text editor back to the document type. Copy the text from the front end back into the backend (hopefully you don't have a million pages), and always perform a backup of the site, database and all, before attempting fixes of this nature.

Comment: reverted the umbraco database! everything sorted

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried access Developer/Data Types/Richtext editor and set again the options that you want?

Comment: What option have you selected for Render Control?

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestions, i have reverted back to the previous database state.